# Menu de navegação com flexbox

Tags: css3, flexbox

Quando crio uma lista `li` de navegação `nav`, os elementos se alinham sem espaçamento e permanecem um ao lado do outro com `padding-right = 0`.
Essa lista esta aninhada em um `header` que possui `display:flex` para organizar  dois elementos `h1` e a lista de navegação `nav`.

É possível criar o espaçamento entre ancoras `a` ou itens de uma lista `li` usando **flexbox** ? 
Como faço para alinhar o titulo `h1` na esquerda e a lista a direita com espaçamento entre os links `a` da lista `li` ?

```css
header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 55px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content:space-between;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}

ul {
 display: flex;
 justify-content:space-between;
}

li {
 flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1><a href="#">Museu Nacional</a></h1>
 <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3 is longer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Antes de iniciar a minha resposta***, abaixo eu deixo **dois (2) links** que são referentes a assuntos pertinentes a sua pergunta. Lendo os mesmos com calma e treinando você conseguirá subir para um nível maior.

> **1) [FLEXBOX (GUIA COMPLETO)](https://origamid.com/projetos/flexbox-guia-completo/)**
>
> **2) [MÉTODOLOGIAS BEM (PADRÕES DE CSS)](http://getbem.com/introduction/)**

***Antes da leitura de minha resposta*** necessito que tenha lido o conteúdo **(1)** acima!
Caso já tenha lido podemos prosseguir...  Agora irei explicar o que é **Flex Container**, **Itens Flex** e o que eu fiz na **definição de estilos (CSS)** e na **marcação de texto (HTML)**, **vamos lá?**

**O que é um Flex Container?**

> É uma **tag** que envolve **(é pai)** dos **itens flex** e ao indicar o atributo `display: flex` esta determinada **tag** passa a ser um **Flex Container**.
>
> **Observação:** Seguindo a **metodologia BEM de padrões de CSS** o **Flex Container** é criado dentro de uma **classe** `.container`, `.d-flex` entre outras.

**O que são Itens Flex?**

> Sem mais delongas, são os **filhos** do **Flex Container**, ou seja, os **itens flex** estão ***depois da abertura*** e ***antes do fechamento da tag*** do **Flex Container**.

**Como funciona nossa definição de estilos (CSS) e marcação de texto (HTML5)?**

> `<nav>` e `<ul>`: **São Flex Container**
>
> `<div>` e `<li>`: **São Flex Itens**

```
<div “container d-flex”> // DIV 1
    <div><h1>Sou filho e Iten Flex da DIV 1 e irmão da DIV 3</h1></div> 
    <div><h2> Sou filho e Iten Flex da DIV 1 e irmão da DIV 2</h2></div> 
</div>
```

Logo abaixo segue o que você necessitava, lembrando que **não estou seguindo nenhuma boas práticas, metodologias entre outros**. **É apenas para aprendizagem**.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

div:first-child {
  flex-grow: 0;
  background-color:green
}

div:last-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color:orange
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-right: 4px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div>
      <h1><a href="#">Museu Nacional</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3 is longer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Obrigado ! Esclareceu minha questão.

Comment: @Luis disponha!

Comment: como faço para diminuir o espaço entre os itens de lista ?

Comment: @Luis depende muito. Geralmente as pessoas utilizam frameworks onde já contém o algoritmo com a arquitetura devidamente criada e com metodologias utilizadas como por exemplo a BEM. Mas neste caso, como estamos fazendo na "mão" temos alguns modos para fazer isto.. O primeiro é você manipular os `padding` igual eu fiz, pois o `justify-content: space-between` cria automaticamente os espaçamentos, sugiro que leia com atenção a documentação do item (1) a qual te informei na resposta e fique inserindo no código para ver as diferenças e aprender melhor!.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve adicionar a propriedade *justify-content: space-between;* para que o flexbox possa realizar o espaçamento entre os elementos.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: editei a pergunta, veja se pode me ajudar.